# Flatten tree structure represented in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, hierarchical-data

I'm using an engineering calculation package and trying to extract some information from it in a built in reporting tool that allows SQL query

An abbreviated example SQL tables are as follows:

```
Id |  Description  | Ref
---|---------------------
1  |  system 1     |        
3  |  block 4      | 6
3  |  block 4      | 1
5  |  formula1     | 3
6  |  f            | 
7  |  something    | 1
9  |  cheese       | 5
```

The "Ref" column identifies rows that are subrecords of other items.

What I want to do is run a query that will produce a list that will show all items that appear on a each page. As you can see from the table above "ID" is not the unique key; each item can appear in multiple locations within the table. In the example above:

- ID 5 is a subitem of ID3
- ID 3 is a subitem of ID 1 AND ID 6
- ID 1 and ID 6 aren't subitems of anything

So effectively it is representing a tree structure:

```
ID 1
+-------- ID 7
    |---- ID 3
        +---- ID 5
            +---- ID 9
ID 6
+---- ID 3
    +---- ID 5
        +---- ID 9
```

What I'm hoping to is work out which items appear under each top level item (so the end result should be a table where in the "Ref" column only top level items appear):

```
Id |  Description  | Ref
---|---------------------
1  |  system 1     |        
3  |  block 4      | 6
3  |  block 4      | 1
5  |  formula1     | 1
5  |  formula1     | 6
6  |  f            | 
9  |  cheese       | 1
9  |  cheese       | 6
7  |  something    | 1
```

The tree structure can be a total of 5 levels deep

I've been trying to use left joins to build up a list of page references, but I think I'm also going to need to union results tables (because obviously rows like ID=9, ID=5, and ID = 6 have to be duplicated in the final results set). It starts to get a bit messy!

```
WITH   A
AS     (SELECT *
         FROM   [RbdBlocks]),
       B
AS     (SELECT [x].[Id],
               [x].[Description],
               [x].[Page] AS Page1,
               [y].[Page] AS Page2,
        FROM   A AS x
               LEFT OUTER JOIN
               A AS y
               ON y.Id = x.Page)
SELECT *
FROM   B
```

The above gives me some of the nested references, but I'm not sure if there's a better way to get this data together, and to manage the recursion rather than just duplicating the set of queries 4 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Recursive Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (CTEs). They should be able to accomplish exactly what you need.

Have a look at [Example D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#d-using-a-recursive-common-table-expression-to-display-multiple-levels-of-recursion) on the SQL Docs page.

Basically what you'd do in your case is:

- In the "anchor member" of the CTE, select all top-level items
- In the "recursive member" of the CTE, join all of the nested children to the top-level item

Recursive CTEs are not really trivial to understand, so be sure to read the docs carefully.

Comment: Yup - those certainly look like the thing - appears to be just about working, now I'm just up against a bug in the software I'm trying to query!